# spaces in argument from commandline

Tags: c#

i need to parse an argument to a string and it contains spaces so this is what i did:

```
search.exe "/SASE Lab Tools"
```

so now i declared this as a string:

```
        string type = string.Format("{0}", args[0]);
```

then,

i need to do this:

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-R -H -h sinsscm01.ds.net " + type;
```

but my result contains spaces in my `p.StartInfo.Arguments`.

when what i need for my output for `p.StartInfo.Arguments` is:

```
-R -H -h sinsscm01.ds.jdsu.net "/SASE Lab Tools"
```

how do i add `"` `"` into my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include them in your format string, e.g.

```
string type = string.Format("\"{0}\"", args[0]);
```

Or just use concatenation:

```
string type = "\"" + args[0] + "\"";
```

Currently your format string is *effectively* just doing:

```
string type = args[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this should help you:

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-R -H -h sinsscm01.ds.net \"" + type + "\"";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add most characters with a backslash if they have other meanings. such as \t for tab, and \" will give quotes etc.